# Group rows in Pandas DataFrame based on complex condition

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause, multiple-tables, multi-level

I have a basic dataframe, structured like this:

```
             Col1
Ind1 Ind2
0    key1    12
     key2    35
1    key3    56
     key4    24
     key5    65
```

...and another one like this:

```
    ColA
0   key1
1   else
2   else
3   key3
```

What I need is the mean value of df1, grouped based on whether Ind2 is in df2 or not.
This is what I tried without success; the message sais "Lengths must match to compare" -- but of course, they don't.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ind1': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'ind2': ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5'], 'col1': [12, 35, 56, 24, 65]}, )
df1.set_index(['ind1', 'ind2'], inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['key1', 'else', 'else', 'key3']})

print (df1.groupby(df1.index.levels[1] in df2.get_values()).mean())
```

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to check whether an element of `df1.index.levels[1]` is in `df2.ColA` (since you need a value for each row). The syntax you wrote won't get you that. Instead, you should try

```
df1.groupby(df1.index.levels[1].isin(df2.ColA)).mean()
```

Note the `isin` function that returns `True`/`False` for every element, and the fact that I refer directly to `df2.ColA`, since it is the column that contains the values (reffering to `df2` instead would search for the values in the column names of `df2`).